# Can the acf function properly compute autocorrelation with a binary vector?

Tags: r

Hi supposed I have a vector consisting of 0's and 1's; will the default acf function be able to calculate this correctly?

```
set.seed ( 12 )
bin = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=5000)
acf (bin )
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it?

Comment: @user2554330 the issue is that  acf computes with Pearson correlation, which I think should only suitable for continuous variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Your example doesn't work because it is completely random. But we can create a binomial sample with an oscillating probability of 1s and 0s like this:

```r
times <- seq(0, 20 * pi, pi / 6)
probs <- sin(times) * 0.5 + 0.5
```

Our probability of getting a 1 at each time step looks like this:

```
plot(times, probs, type = "l")
```

[image]

And we can generate a sample like this:

```r
set.seed(1)
samp <- rbinom(length(times), 1, probs)

samp
#>   [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>  [38] 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
#>  [75] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
#> [112] 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

And we can demonstrate that `acf` correctly identifies the autocorrelation:

```
acf(samp)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks your simulation is a great to show this, however I'm still a bit confused and reason why I ask in the first place is that  acf computes the Pearson correlation? Is'nt that only suitable for continuous variables? but in your example its clear that it still works.

Comment: @Ahdee Pearson correlation may not be the best way of comparing similarity between two binary vectors, but it is still definable (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103801/is-it-meaningful-to-calculate-pearson-or-spearman-correlation-between-two-boolea/103806)), and clearly gives results that work well enough for the purposes of autocorrelation

Comment: Not sure I'm convinced by the example:  those are independent observations, so the true correlation is zero between any pair.  What you're seeing is the failure of the ACF to measure correlation in a non-stationary series.

Comment: @user2554330 I'm not sure I understand that. Perhaps I'm being naive, but if the probability of the occurrence of a 1 is a periodically repeating function, then the acf will detect the periodicity of that function. I would venture this would be the main reason for wanting to do an acf in this case. But I would be prepared to be proved wrong on that point.

Comment: @AllanCameron:  the ACF is supposed to detect correlation.  Those values are uncorrelated, they just look correlated because of the nonstationarity.

Comment: @user2554330 I think my point is that it is a valid method of detecting the presence of cyclical non-stationarity.

Comment: @AllanCameron:  Okay, I agree with that.  If you view it as a test of the hypothesis of stationary white noise, it's okay.  I was viewing it as an estimator of the autocorrelation function.